# Wordpress как правильно изменить\расширить плагин?

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Согласно документации wordpress для изменения темы, используется дочерняя тема, что вполне логично. Но как быть с плагинами?

Т.е задача такова что бы внести корректировки в код плагина при этом не трогая исходный код. Есть ли возможность подмены файла плагина по аналогии с дочерними темами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, такой возможности нет. Можно расширять классы плагина в своем плагине или модифицировать его работу через хуки. Все это при условии, что нужные классы и хуки определены в "родительском" плагине.

Comment: т.е если я правильно понял, если что-то в плагине не устраивает, правь код самого плагина?

Comment: @user199588 если не удается сделать через классы или хуки, то - да. Так и приходилось поступать в некоторых случаях.

Answer (score 0):

> Т.е задача такова что бы внести корректировки в код плагина при этом не трогая исходный код. Есть ли возможность подмены файла плагина по аналогии с дочерними темами?

Если у плагина есть API или хотя бы проверка существования функций, то можно их изменить в своём плагине или файле функций темы. Если нет, то ой. Писать разве что разработчику, чтобы сделал проверку функций.

PS. Речь про php-код. С css проблем нет, их всегда можно переопределить.

Comment: В смысле ` в своем плагине`?

Comment: В смысле сделать свой плагин, который будет делать сказанное выше..